# Spatial join and aggregate two different layers in QGIS

Tags: join, polygon, qgis

I have a polygon layer that consists of different zones (grid).

in that same area I have a second polygon that classified in 6 different land-use types (residential commercial, retail etc...).  This second polygon consists of many small 'parcels' of buildings, where each parcel is classified into a different land-use type.

I would like to know how to calculate the total number of parcel in each zone, and how to count the number of parcels (buildings) per each land-use type, for each zone.

Is there a quick way to combine 'spatial join' with perhaps 'aggregate function'.
Or any other useful way to make this ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia9pt.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5WTQ.jpg)

I tried to make a spatial join and aggregate